# Fade up content with JavaScript or CSS (scroll effect)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to recreate a special kind of scroll I've noticed on a website.

1. Go to https://basicagency.com/yir/;
2. Wait for the `EXPLORE` button to appear and click it;
3. Scroll down in the new view.

How can I the content use the same scroll effect? It seems that instead of you being going down, the site comes up.

I've been able to create a page that looks just the same, but I have no idea how to do that.

```js
/* i don't have idea */
```

```css
*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 max-width: 100vw;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

main{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 10vw 90vw;
 grid-template-rows: 100vh;
}

nav{
 background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);

 z-index: 1;

 width: 10vw;
 height: 100vh;

 left: 0;
 top: 0;

 position: fixed;
}

#c1{
 background: blue /*url(../img/back.jpeg) center no-repeat*/;
 background-size: cover;

 grid-column: 1 / -1;
 grid-row: 1 / -1;

 z-index: 0;
}

#c2{
 background: black;

 grid-column: 1 / -1;
 grid-row: 1 / -1;

 z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <title></title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>

 <nav>
   
 </nav>

 <main>

  <content id="c1">
   
  </content>

 </main>

 <main>
  
  <content id="c2">
   
  </content>

 </main>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey there & welcome to StackOverflow Henrique! Your question is incomplete and has little chances to get answered as is. Please read the **[How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** article & edit your question adding more information.

Comment: Basically provide something you worked on. This is not a charity debugging portal! (if you need help with this, read up on how to create a **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**)

Comment: The site listens for the scroll or wheel event which triggers an animation to show a new block of content. You can write this yourself with javascript or look into libraries such as https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page1.  You can also explore a fairly new CSS property to allow scroll snapping, this might help: https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/